# Is worth it to keep my two rental properties or to sell them right now?

Tags: taxes

I have two rental properties in two different states, PA and NC. My PA home was a second home for some years, which just a year ago I turned into a rental property. I made a big mistake doing that because of the huge impact it will have on taxes when I sell. That property has been just rented for 1 year and the other in NC has been for 4 years. The price of the homes have not increased significantly. I will not get much from them when I sell them. Also, the rents just cover the mortgage of the homes but for maintenance and repairs it comes straight from my pocket. I feel frustrated that I have not much money on the properties and now that I learned about the huge impact that taxes will cause me, plus that I am not making any money for me to keep from my rentals. Should I sell now? I have read that in the case of rentals I should keep them for the rest of my life. I'm not sure what to do. Thank you.

Comment: Is the large tax burden because you took depreciation expense in prior years and it lowered your cost basis? You could look at as paying taxes now on what you could have paid taxes on previously.

Comment: I took depreciation on both of my properties just for one year( last year) Prior to that, I kept my PA home as a second home and never did that. The same with my NC home, although my NC home was a rental home since the beginning 4 years ago. No matter weather you took depreciation now or later or not at all, there will still be major tax implications when you sell, the capital gain taxes.

Comment: But the cost basis is what you paid for it, less any depreciation taken. That's why I'm wondering why you will owe capital gains tax if you "will not get much from them when you sell them". You only pay tax on the _gain_ you make, not the total sales price.

Answer (score 2):

This question is likely to be closed for primarily being opinion based, but I believe that I can provide a clear cut answer here.

Owning rental properties is work, and for some it is not pleasant work.  You seem to fit in that category.  Having the properties be out of state, expands the amount of work necessary and it often leads to additional expenses.

Assume you had a job that you did not like, but also paid you only enough money for gas and tolls to get to the work location.  Would you continue to work there?  Most assuredly "No".

Same thing here, **sell the properties and be done with this**.  Owning rental real estate is seductive, but it is work and it has to be work that you enjoy.  You also need very large contingency funds, income outside of the rentals, and profitability.  Having sizable mortgages on rentals reduces the likelihood of profitability.

Comment: Having rentals in general is not the problem. I know they require a lot of work. My question is about the taxes when I decide to sell. The more time I keep the rental properties, the more taxes I will have to pay. Is it worth to have rental properties at all? I was planning to keep them and pay them off for my retirement.

Comment: You only pay taxes on your gain though, so more taxes means you're making more money. You could go live in one for 2 years prior to selling to avoid a large chunk of tax, at least under current tax law. Just having mortgage covered isn't ideal, but you're still gaining equity without too much investment of your own. If you don't think the area will grow, then it's harder to justify keeping them, as a down-turn could mean you can't even cover mortgage with the rent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to leave this as a comment.  But have you looked at the [1031 exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_Revenue_Code_section_1031)?  This could potentially allow you to sell the PA/NC houses and purchase a rental property closer to where you live.

I would also advise you to post your question on [Bigger Pockets](https://www.biggerpockets.com/) as the website has a Real Estate forum where other investors, CPAs, can give you suggestions.

Lastly, I would recommend you not to give your hopes on being a rental property investor.  Sounds like only your portfolio needs to change.